# Cannot match any routes. URL Segment in Angular 11

Tags: angular

Im having this message when entering to an INVALID route and I thought that It should render the home page as expected but I'm getting a uncaught promise.

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { RegisterComponent } from "./index/register/register.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () => import("./index/index.module").then((m) => m.IndexModule),
  },
  {
    path: "portal",
    loadChildren: () => import("./portal/portal-module/portal.module").then((m) => m.PortalModule),
  },
  {
    path: "signup",
    component: RegisterComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: "legacy" })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

```
vendor.js:32650 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'uadjbkdasjkndas'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'uadjbkdasjkndas'
```

I already tried this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () => import("./index/index.module").then((m) => m.IndexModule),
  },
  {
    path: "portal",
    loadChildren: () => import("./portal/portal-module/portal.module").then((m) => m.PortalModule),
  },
  {
    path: "signup",
    component: RegisterComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "portal",
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
];
```

And the behaviour is that everything is going to portal, also all the ones that are inside the index.

I've tried also adding pathMatch to the index routes.

Comment: Set a wildcard route: `{ path: '**', component: <component-name> }`

Comment: you are trying to access a route that wasn't defined. You either need a catchall, or a route with a parameter such as `"path": ":myParam"`

Answer (score 1):

The first route inside the Routes object only accepts an empty path (or ""). To redirect any path not listed inside Routes to a specific component or module, add the wildcard path to it and it should work.

Snippet:

```
{ path: '**', component: <component-name> }
```

So in your case only change the path attribute:

```
{
    path: "**",
    loadChildren: () => import("./index/index.module").then((m) => m.IndexModule),
  },
```

References: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I've tried this and now everyroute is going to **

Comment: Put this path as the last inside your Routes Array. Put "portal" and "signup" before the "**"

Comment: well I guess my question wasn't clear at all.. What I wanted is to redirect to portal if the path does not exists. If I do as u mention all the links are going to "/"
```const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () => import("./index/index.module").then((m) => m.IndexModule),
  },
  {
    path: "portal",
    loadChildren: () => import("./portal/portal-module/portal.module").then((m) => m.PortalModule),
  },
  {
    path: "signup",
    component: RegisterComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "/portal",
  },
];
```

Comment: Try to add property pathMatch: 'full' to the object and remove the slash from "/portal". It should work as you described.

Comment: And is still not working, the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle not found route using wildcard routes. Here the sequence of route matter so wildcard route should always be added to end of the array

Please update your routing as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: "",
  loadChildren: () => import("./index/index.module").then((m) => m.IndexModule),
 },
 {
  path: "portal",
  loadChildren: () => import("./portal/portal-module/portal.module").then((m) => m.PortalModule),
 },
 {
  path: "signup",
  component: RegisterComponent,
 },
 {
  path: "**",
  redirectTo: "",
  pathMatch: 'full'
 }
];
```

PS: you can read [this](https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-wildcard-routes) to know more about wildcard routes

Comment: Please update the answer to explain the catch-all

Comment: Added link for reference

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a wild card is to use a route with a parameter so that you can access the value in your application.

So, you would then create a param path (where the parameter is some value prefixed with a `:`)

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ""
  },
  {
    path: "portal"
  },
  {
    path: "signup"
  },
  {
    path: ":example"
  },
];
```

Then in your application you can access it:

```js
export class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(p => {
      if ('example' in p) {
        // do something with `p['example']`
      }
    })
  }
}
```